# Orthogonality Problem true/sometimes true/false.

Tags: linear-algebra

**If $V = span\left \{ v_1,v_2 \right \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$, and if a vector $w$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$, then $w$ is in $V^\perp $.**

I found that the trivial case supports the statement and since $V^\perp = \left \{ x \in {}\mathbb{R}:<x,v_1>=0,<x,v_2>=0\right \}$ non zero vectors would also work.
Therefore, I think this is true.

Comment: As a set $\mathbb{R}^{3} \not\subset \mathbb{R}^{4}$. I'm not sure this actually matters but you should rephrase the question. You have $V span\{ v_{1},v_{2} \} \subset W\subset \mathbb{R}^{4}$ with $W$ a 3 dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product is bilinear, so if $w\cdot v_1=w\cdot v_2=0$, then $w\cdot(c_1v_1+c_2v_2)=0$.

Comment: Since all the vectors are orthogonal, does that prove the statement to always be right?